# System of differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this system of linear differential equations:

\begin{cases}
\dot f=2f -g,  \\[2ex]
\dot g=4f-2g,
\end{cases}

knowing the initial conditions $f(0)=3$ and $f(0)=5$.

The hint I have is to use the equation $\dot F=AF$ with a $2\times 2$ Matrix $A$ and find the solution $F: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$, using $\exp(tA)=I+tA+ \frac12 (tA)^2+\dots$

I didn't understand that well the hint, but I tried solving the system by finding $\det(A)$.

The solution I got is $\lambda=0$ and the eigenvector 
$v_0= \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      1C_1\\
      2C_2
    \end{array}
\right] $.
But this case is a bit strange and I'm not sure if I'm right.

Can someone explain what's different in this exercise, and how do I need to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve the system $\vec{F}'(t) = A\vec{F}(t)$ with $$A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 4 & -2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ The solution is given by
$$
\vec{F}(t) = e^{tA} \vec{F}(0) 
$$
and you need to find $$e^{tA} = I + tA + \frac{(tA)^2}{2!} + \ldots$$

Can you take it from here?

**UPD HINT2**

Compute $A^2$ and the above Taylor series will simplify greatly.

Comment: You have written the multiplication on the left; it should be on the right.

Comment: What concerns the Matrix A is clear, but I still don't get what comes after...

Comment: @Ian thanks, fixed

Comment: @Ergo can you please be more specific? what do you not understand exactly? Do you know what $e^A$ means when $A$ is a matrix?

Comment: For example I don't understand what you mentioned. There is clearly a lack of knowledge about this systems, I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing.
My way to procede in these cases is to use the assumption that $ f=C_1e^{\lambda x}$ and the same for $g$ and then, in order to find that matrix $A$ and the vector $v$ I substitute the assumption in the system.
Knowing the relation $\lambda v=Av$ I find $\lambda$ with $det(A)$ and I usually just had to values for $\lambda$ that helped me to find the constants.

Comment: @Ergo your approach isn't always correct. E.g. here, it won't work. Definition of $e^{tA}$ (it is also a matrix) is from the Taylor series in the answer. You can simplifyit greatly by just computing $A^2$. What do you get? Then multiply by $\vec{F}(0)$ on the right to get the answer...

Answer (score 1):

In the generic* situation, the solution to a first order linear system with constant coefficients is of the form

$$F(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i e^{\lambda_i t} v_i$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues, $v_i$ are the corresponding eigenvectors, $c_i$ are constants depending on the initial condition, and $n$ is the number of equations.

However, it can happen that the coefficient matrix is not diagonalizable, meaning that it does not have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. This turns out to occur in your case: your matrix has a double eigenvalue of zero, and it is not the zero matrix.

There are some workarounds in this situation. One brute force approach uses the power series definition of the matrix exponential explicitly. In this case $A^2=0$, so the series just reads $e^{At}=I+At$. This is usually not a good approach, though, at least not in hand calculations.

Another workaround uses the Jordan normal form. If $A=P J P^{-1}$ for any invertible $P$ and any $J$, then $e^{At} = P e^{Jt} P^{-1}$. So if we had a matrix $J$ which was similar to $A$ and for which it was easy to compute the exponential, then everything would be nice. It turns out that there always is one. In the diagonalizable case it is diagonal. In the nondiagonalizable case it is *triangular*.

In your particular case you have the eigenvector $(1,2)^T$, and the generalized eigenvector satisfies

$$Ax=(1,2)^T.$$

That is, $(A-\lambda I)x$ is equal to the "defective" eigenvector $(1,2)^T$ (an eigenvector corresponding to a double eigenvalue which only has one eigenvector). By row reduction we find $x_1-x_2/2=1/2$, so one generalized eigenvector is $(1,1)^T$. Then the theory of the Jordan normal form tells us that if $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $A=P J P^{-1}$. This reduces the problem to computing $e^{Jt}$, or equivalently to solving the system of differential equations

$$x_1'=x_2 \\
x_2' = 0.$$

This system is *triangular*, which makes it straightforward to solve using back-substitution. We find $x_2=x_2(0),x_1=x_1(0)+x_2(0)t$.

A third way (which I have only seen in one source) uses the fact that if $P$ is a polynomial and $P(A)=0$ then $P(D)e^{At}=0$, where $D$ is the operator of differentation with respect to $t$. Therefore the entries of $e^{At}$ each satisfy the scalar equation $P(D)e_{ij}=0$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we can always take $P$ to be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Also, we know the initial conditions for this equation, since $\frac{d^k}{dt^k} e^{At}=A^k$ at time zero. Thus

$$e^{At}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} N_i A^i$$

where $N_i$ is the solution to $P(D)y=0$ with $y^{(i)}(0)=1$ and all other derivatives beginning at zero. The collection $\{ N_0,\dots,N_{n-1} \}$ is called the natural fundamental set for $P(D)y=0$. This reduces the problem to computing the characteristic polynomial and then solving a certain scalar equation. In high dimensions this is a bad idea (computing the characteristic polynomial and finding its roots is hard) but in low dimensions, especially in hand calculations, this is a really nice way to proceed.

* When I say "generic", I mean that if you choose a matrix with real entries "at random", this occurs with probability 1. It does not mean "general" (as the rest of the discussion demonstrates).

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do this. note that 
$$\frac d{dt}\left(2f-g\right)=2 \dot f-\dot g = 2(2f-g)-(4f-2g) = 0.$$ therefore, $$2f - g = C, \text{ where $C$ is a constant}\tag 1 $$ 
using $(1)$ in the second equation $$\dot g = 4f - 2g \to 2\dot f=4f+2(C-2f) = 2C$$ which has the solution $$f = Ct + D, \quad g = 2f-C = 2Ct+2D-C \tag 2$$ 
you can fix $C$ and $D$ from the initial condition.

the first column of $e^{tA}$ is the solution corresponding to the initial values $f = 1, g = 0.$ from $(2),$  this is $\pmatrix{1+2t\\4t}$ corresponding to $D= 1, C= 2.$ in the same way the second column is $\pmatrix{-t\\1-2t}$ corresponding to $D= 0, C= -1.$
that is $$e^{At} = \pmatrix{1+2t&-t\\4t&1-2t}= I + tA.$$

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LA_Eigen.aspx), [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolutionsToSystems.aspx), and [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RealEigenvalues.aspx), $$A = \begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\4&-2\\\end{pmatrix},$$ $$\lambda_1=2\text{ and }\lambda_2=-2,$$ $$\text{and }\vec{\eta}_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\end{pmatrix}\text{& }\vec{\eta}_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\\end{pmatrix}.$$The solution is then, $$
c_1e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{-2t}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^{-2t}\\-2c_2e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix},$$and$$\begin{cases}f(t)=c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^{-2t}\\g(t)=-2c_2e^{-2t}.\end{cases}$$